# How to use social plugin : Comment?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created fan page.I am using iframe application.I want to add comment on facebook fan page.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: Hi visited that page.After clicking on get code button.It provides code details that is in HTML5.Does I need to used java script api for doing that.I am really not getting.